# Yii2 creates new session instead of opening existing

Tags: php, session, yii, yii2

I am working on a simple logic of storing my shopping cart in session using Yii2 native **yii\web\Session**.
Every time I add an item to a cart I call a method:

```
public function actionAdd( ) {

    $id = Yii::$app->request->get('id');
    $product = Product::findOne($id);

    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $session->open();

    $cart = new Cart();
    $cart->addToCart($product);

    $this->layout = false;
    return $this->render('cart-modal', compact('session'));
}
```

this method works with a Cart model and adds my item to the session:

```
public function addToCart($product, $qty = 1) {

    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$product->id])) {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product->id]['qty'] += $qty;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product->id] = [
            'qty' => $qty,
            'title' => $product->title,
            'price' => $product->price,
            'image' => $product->image,
        ];
    }
}
```

and all goes well until I try add another item. 
Then Yii instead of opening existing session creates a new one with this last item I've add. What can be the reason of this kind of behavior?

I'm working on a local web server OpenServer and haven't changed any setting that might be related to sessions.

Comment: Try session_status() at the beginning of your action to see the status of your session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've figured. The problem was with my server. As soon as I moved to VPS this issue has gone.

Answer (score 2):

You are basically not using `session` component at all. Change your code to:

```
public function actionAdd( ) {

    $id = Yii::$app->request->get('id');
    $product = Product::findOne($id);

    // REMOVE THIS
    // session is started automatically when using component
    // $session = Yii::$app->session;
    // $session->open();

    $cart = new Cart();
    $cart->addToCart($product);

    $this->layout = false;
    return $this->render('cart-modal', compact('session'));
}

public function addToCart($product, $qty = 1) {

    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    if ($session->has('cart')) {
        $cart = $session['cart']; // you can not modify session subarray directly
    } else {
        $cart = [];
    }
    if(isset($cart[$product->id])) {
        $cart[$product->id]['qty'] += $qty;
    } else {
        $cart[$product->id] = [
            'qty' => $qty,
            'title' => $product->title,
            'price' => $product->price,
            'image' => $product->image,
        ];
    }
    $session->set('cart', $cart);
}
```

I hope it helps. If not it means problem is somewhere else but nevertheless you should use `session` component properly.